# Issue with New-DFSNFolderTarget cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to automate repointing DFS folders. This is my current script:

```
$ft=get-dfsnfolder "\\test.dfs.domain\testpath\zzTop\*" | get-dfsnfoldertarget

$ft|% { 

    if ($_.targetpath -like "*blah*") {
    
        new-dfsnfoldertarget -Path $_.path -State online -TargetPath ($_.targetpath).replace("\\blah.test.domain\testpath\zzTop","\\new.test.domain\testpath\zzTop")
        
     }
}
```

I'm receiving a very weird error that is completely non-specific and makes this basically impossible to debug below:

```
new-dfsnfoldertarget : Can't add DFS namespace folder target "\\blah.test.domain\testpath\zzTop\2two"
At C:\Users\my_username\Desktop\ChangeDFSTargetTEST.ps1:2 char:46
+ ... *blah*") {new-dfsnfoldertarget -Path $_.path -State online -TargetP ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_DfsNamespaceFolderTarget:ROOT\Microsoft\...aceFolderTarget) [New-DfsnFolderTarget], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 80,New-DfsnFolderTarget
 
new-dfsnfoldertarget : A general error occurred that is not covered by a more specific error code.
At C:\Users\my_username\Desktop\ChangeDFSTargetTEST.ps1:2 char:46
+ ... *blah*") {new-dfsnfoldertarget -Path $_.path -State online -TargetP ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_DfsNamespaceFolderTarget:ROOT\Microsoft\...aceFolderTarget) [New-DfsnFolderTarget], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 80,New-DfsnFolderTarget
```

I'm running this script as admin on the box that is hosting and managing the DFS, so no issues with remote connections. I also have a script to offline these paths which works fine and also uses the "$_.targetpath -like "*blah*".

Also, if I run the command:

```
new-dfsnfoldertarget -Path $_.path -State online -TargetPath ($_.targetpath).replace("\\blah.test.domain\testpath\zzTop","\\new.test.domain\testpath\zzTop")
```

Replacing the variables with the strings that are fed into it automatically (so running it manually), it works fine. This is from a Server 2019 Standard box with PSVersion 5.1.17763.1490.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be terribly relevant, but I realized I had set up DFS using an admin share path which is locked down almost completely so the testing I was doing was useless.

This script works fine if your DFS is healthy.